# Merge [laws] and [legal]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

So we have two tags: [laws](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws) and [legal](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal).

The first has a wiki:

> For questions related to laws, ordinances, rules, or regulations
>   governing the behavior of pets and their handlers in public places.

But, I would think that it would be a subset of [legal](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal). So should we merge the two, make [legal](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) the parent, and copy the wiki over?

Comment: Legal would be the meta tag but laws would be the object tag. Generally you want the object tag on questions rather than the meta.  That said we have other meta tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makes sense to me - they are talking about the same thing, laws are just a subset of legal related issues, and I don't see any reason to separate the two.

Comment: The questions under legal are referring to laws.  Merge to legal.

Answer (score 2):

Suggesting [laws](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/laws) as the parent and [legal](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) as the child.  Just my predjuiduce from searching.  I think laws is the better word.

But fine with the other way if out voted.